# How to properly add two network interfaces with Netplan?

Tags: netplan

#### Problem

Please check the picture here first,  a visualization of my network plan.

[image: Network plan diagram]

I'm trying to add two networks on same Ubuntu 18 server, one of them is vlan tagged. When I add the second network, internal users can't access to this server from public IP. But anyone outside can access from public IP without any problem.

#### What I want to do

- I have default network `192.168.10.0/24` and a VLAN 300 tagged network `192.168.30.0/24`.
- I want to add both 10.x and 30.x networks to one server, because I want it to access both networks.
- This server must be able to access both `192.168.10.0/24` and `192.168.30.0/24` networks.
- This server must be reachable from everywhere via its public IP.

#### Step by step what I do

- All wifi users are connect to `192.168.10.0/24` network.
- All servers are using VLAN 300 network `192.168.30.0/24`.
- These servers are reachable via their Public IPs from internet. Internal wifi users can also access via these public IPs.
- When I add a second network to this ubuntu server, users can't access server via its public IP.

I tried many different things with netplan, and checked all the examples on netplan.io.

Here is my current simplest configuration:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens18: # this one is vlan tagged on Proxmox. So it can get 30.x IP.
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.30.101/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.30.1
            routes:
              - to: 192.168.30.0/24
                via: 192.168.30.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
        ens19:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.10.101/24]
            # gateway4: 192.168.10.1
            routes:
              - to: 192.168.10.0/24
                via: 192.168.10.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
    version: 2
```

I also tried things using vlans:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens18:
            addresses: [192.168.10.101/24]
            # gateway4: 192.168.10.1
            routes:
              - to: 192.168.10.0/24
                via: 192.168.10.101
                table: 5
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: 192.168.10.1
                table: 5
            routing-policy:
              - to: 192.168.10.0/24
                table: 5
            nameservers:
              addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
    vlans:
        vlan30:
            id: 300
            link: ens18
            gateway4: 192.168.30.1
            addresses: [192.168.30.101/24]
            routes:
              - to: 192.168.30.0/24
                via: 192.168.30.101
                table: 6
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: 192.168.30.1
                table: 6
            routing-policy:
              - to: 192.168.30.0/24
                table: 6
            nameservers:
              addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
```

Comment: If ens18 is on a vlan tagged port, you do not need to do any vlan configuration in netplan for this.  The one thing I see that's incorrect in your first example is that you have listed a route to the local network via a gateway, which is wrong. You should not be declaring routes for your local networks, you only need the `gateway4` to set a default route.  I don't know if this will be enough to fix your networking problem or if we will need to investigate further after this change.

Comment: @slangasek As you suggested, I deleted gateway4 in the first example, when I delete the default route, I cant connect to internet. And 10.x network users still can't access to this server.

Also In the first example, ens18 was on a vlan tagged port, but in second example it was not on vlan tagged port. Don't make it confuse you, my point is the problem occurs whenever I add a second network.

Comment: I did not suggest deleting gateway4. I suggested deleting the incorrect /local routes/ that you have added, and leaving gateway4 in place.

Comment: @slangasek Oh yes my mistake. Deleting the local routes that I added brings me back to where I start. So I tried [this](https://imgur.com/XLCg4VC) and [this](https://imgur.com/6CFIUtB) but nothing changes. Server still can access 192.168.10.x routes, but anyone on 192.168.10.x route can't access server via public IP. But when I remove the ens19 interface entirely, then everything works, but server can't access to 192.168.10.x routes then. Btw, you said delete the incorrect routes but thats my question, I don't know what is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually related to a policy rule on our FortiGate firewall which I didn't mention in the original question. I used `Policy Lookup` tool from `IPv4 Policy` page to inspect the issue and modified accordingly, then it is solved.